# Stop typing text when element is focused

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component with typing text, this effect add/remove word and write new word:

```
<template>
  <span
    id="textCode"
    contenteditable="true"
    spellcheck="false"
    style="width: 800px"
    v-text="displayText.join('')"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    speed: {
      type: Number,
      default: 100
    },
    deleteSpeed: {
      type: Number,
      default: 30
    },
    nextWordInterval: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1200
    },
    words: {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      displayText: [],
      currentWord: '',
      wordIdx: 0,
      timeoutSpeed: null,
      isWaitingNextWord: false
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.start()
  },
  methods: {
    start () {
      if (this.words && this.words.length > 0 && !document.querySelector('#textCode').contains(document.activeElement)) {
        this.currentWord = this.words[this.wordIdx].split('')
        this.timeoutSpeed = this.speed
        this.animate = setTimeout(this.type, this.timeoutSpeed)
      }
    },
    type () {
      if (this.currentWord.length > 0) {
        this.displayText.push(this.currentWord.shift())
        // if done typing, wait for a while
      } else if (!this.isWaitingNextWord && this.currentWord.length === 0 && this.displayText.length === this.words[this.wordIdx].length) {
        this.timeoutSpeed = this.nextWordInterval
        this.isWaitingNextWord = true
        // if done typing, then delete
      } else if (this.currentWord.length === 0 && this.displayText.length > 0) {
        this.timeoutSpeed = this.deleteSpeed
        this.displayText.pop()
        // if done typing & deleting
      } else if (this.currentWord.length === 0 && this.displayText.length === 0) {
        // change words
        if (this.wordIdx < (this.words.length - 1)) {
          this.wordIdx++
        } else {
          // reset
          this.wordIdx = 0
        }

        this.timeoutSpeed = this.speed
        this.isWaitingNextWord = false
        this.currentWord = this.words[this.wordIdx].split('')
        this.displayText.push(this.currentWord.shift())
      }

      setTimeout(this.type, this.timeoutSpeed)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I need stop typing text, when element span is focused. How I can do it? I try do in method start:

`!document.querySelector('#textCode').contains(document.activeElement)`

But is not work.. I checked. Maybe is there another method to solve this problem? Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a `"focus"` Event lietener on your element? Also, use `this.tOut = setTimeout(this.type, this.timeoutSpeed)` so that you can (on focus) do `clearTimeout(this.tOut)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan So I have `this.animate = setTimeout(this.type, this.timeoutSpeed)`. When I do `clearTimeout(this.animate)` on focus so not working (

Comment: Make sure `this` is referring to your instance.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yep, of course, referring.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I have in mounted start method, If I remove, then working, but I need default start typing.. On focus only stop.